# Why can't I get the source code by apktool?

Tags: java, android, decompiler, apktool, jd-gui

I use Apktool,dex2jar and jd-gui to decompile an apk,
and I get the classes-dex2jar.jar successfully,

[image]

but when I put it in the jd-gui, there is just one package (the dependency package)
like this:

[image]

How can I get the other source code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using apktool + dex2jar, maybe you can try the one shot tool [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx). It will ask for the apk as input and directly output the decompiled source and resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get full source code from apk using "APK Easy Tool".
Of course, it's impossible to get java file but you can get that corresponding smali code.
You can download it from this URL:

https://apk-easy-tool.en.lo4d.com/windows